# High order function thats has for input a list of functions and a list of elements and applies the functions to the elements

Tags: haskell

As the title suggests i am trying to implement a high order function declared as

```
Ord u => [v->u]->[v]->[u]
```

that has inputs a) a list of functions of any type and a range of values of any type and b) a list of elements of the same type and then it will return a list that is the result of all elements that occured from applying a function from the given list to an element from the given list in ascending order without repetitive values.

i was trying to implement it with the foldr function with no luck.
i thought that i can index with zip the functions as a pair so they will be applied one by one with the foldr function. bellow that i created a insertion sort so i can sort the final list

```
apply :: Ord u => [v->u]->[v]->[u]             
apply f y = insSort (foldr(\(i, x) y -> x:y ) (zip [1..] f))

insSort :: Ord u => [u] -> [u]
insSort (h:t) = insert h (insSort t)
insSort [] = []

insert :: Ord u => u -> [u] -> [u]
insert n (h:t)
            | n <= h = n : h : t
            | otherwise = h : insert n t
insert n [] = [n]
```

for example some inputs with the output:

```
>apply [abs] [-1]
[1]

>apply [(^2)] [1..5]
[1,4,9,16,25]

>apply [(^0),(0^),(\x->div x x),(\x->mod x x)] [1..1000]
[0,1]

>apply [head.tail,last.init] ["abc","aaaa","cbbc","cbbca"]
"abc"

> apply [(^2),(^3),(^4),(2^)] [10]
[100,1000,1024,10000]

>apply [(*5)] (apply [(‘div‘5)] [1..100])
[0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100]
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt with foldr? :)

Comment: @user54264611634646244 of course, i just edited it in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apply :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
```

First of all, this signature matches that of the standard [`<*>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--62-) function, which is part of the [`Applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative) class.

```
class Applicative f where
    pure :: a -> f a
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Setting `f ~ []` we have `<*> :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]`.

There are at least two sensible ways of writing an `Applicative` instance for lists. The first one takes the Cartesian product of its inputs, pairing every function with every value. If `<*>`'s input lists have length *N* and *M*, the output list will have length *N*M*. `pure` for this specification would put an element in a singleton list, so that `pure id <*> xs = xs`.

```
instance Applicative [] where
    pure x = [x]
    (f:fs) <*> xs = map f xs ++ (fs <*> xs)
```

This is equivalent to [the standard `Applicative` instance for `[]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-739).

The other sensible way of implementing `Applicative` zips the two lists together by applying functions to elements pointwise. If `<*>`'s input lists have length *N* and *M*, the output list will have length *min(N, M)*. `pure` creates an infinite list, so once again `pure id <*> xs = xs`.

```
instance Applicative [] where
    pure x = let xs = x:xs in xs
    [] <*> _ = []
    _ <*> [] = []
    (f:fs) <*> (x:xs) = f x : (fs <*> xs)
```

This instance is available in `base` under [the `ZipList` newtype](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList).